# How to get an information of a webpage with google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with a data base in google spreadsheets where I have the street name, neighborhood, city, state and country informations. What I need to do is search the zip code at Correios website (a brazilian shipping company) and put the information in a cell of my sheet. I'd already tryied to use the importxml function with the xpath of the object that contains the information, but without sucess. Does someone knows how do I get the zip code provided by correios of an adress in google sheets? The webpage of correios:   https://buscacepinter.correios.com.br/app/endereco/index.php

Comment: What URL did you use? I see in firefox's "Developer Tools" that the response is JSON, not XML.

Comment: Actually I used this formula: =IMPORTXML("https://www.linkcorreios.com.br/ceps/buscar-cep?cep_consulta="&F2&"&bt_=Consultar+CEP";"//b";) to get information of a street with the zipcode, but I use the zip code to search for this page. To search with the name of the street I'm really lost.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in your question (full address and zip) so we can test.